# Body class padding top, where is it coming from

Tags: 8

I'm using Drupal 8.4.2 lightning-8.x-2.23 and Boostrap subtheme, Admin Toolbar.
The body class has an injected class of padding-top: 40.4px; for publisher user and padding-top: 79.4px; for admins. I want to make it the same padding. Does anybody know where this style is coming from? I dont see it in any style sheet. In Drupal 7 the admin toolbar had a settings page that allowed for padding top so that it pushes the body below the toolbar.

Logged in as admin body class

```
<body class="toolbar-tray-open toolbar-horizontal toolbar-fixed user-logged-
in path-workbench has-glyphicons" style="padding-top: 79.4px;">
```

Logged in as publisher body class

```
<body class="toolbar-tray-open toolbar-horizontal toolbar-fixed user-logged-
in path-workbench has-glyphicons" style="padding-top: 40.4px;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being done by the core toolbar module. See `updateToolbarHeight` in  `core/modules/toolbar/js/views/ToolbarVisualView.js`.

```
updateToolbarHeight: function updateToolbarHeight() {
  var toolbarTabOuterHeight = $('#toolbar-bar').find('.toolbar-tab').outerHeight() || 0;
  var toolbarTrayHorizontalOuterHeight = $('.is-active.toolbar-tray-horizontal').outerHeight() || 0;
  this.model.set('height', toolbarTabOuterHeight + toolbarTrayHorizontalOuterHeight);

  $('body').css({
    'padding-top': this.model.get('height')
  });

  this.triggerDisplace();
},
```

Comment: Thank you Chance G. Its done automatically now. I have different padding for admin then for all other users. So my workaround was to add a body class for which user they are .role-group_user is now added for all non-admin users. Then I nested a css class to add mode padding for non-admin users. Now both users have the same padding.